# scp permission denied in /tmp directory

Tags: scp, cp, tmp

When I copy a file using scp from a remote location to the /tmp/ directory in local machine, it is successful. However, when I copy another file using scp from the same machine(i.e. remote and local machines are same), I am getting the 'Permission denied' error.

`scp user@host-b:/usr/U91/host-b/trace/server_console_host-b.trc /tmp` is successful.

`scp user@host-a:/usr/U91/host-a/trace/server_console_host-a.trc /tmp` fails with error: `/tmp/server_console_host-a.trc: Permission denied`

Even normal copy fails:
`cp /usr/U91/host-a/trace/server_console_host-a.trc /tmp/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/tmp/server_console_host-a.trc’: Permission denied`

I am unable to understand why scp from remote is successful while others fail.

Note: All the above commands are executed in host-a machine.

Comment: I identified the issue. There was already a file with same name in /tmp that belonged to a different owner so the scp failed since it did not have the permission to overwrite the existing file due to different user. scp worked correctly after removing the file from /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have done some changes to the owner ship of /tmp on host-a?

/tmp should look like this...

```
ls -la / |grep tmp
**drwxrwxrwt.**  16 root root  4096 Dec 31 11:05 tmp
```

May something for you to read about. ;-)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp

Comment: `drwxrwxrwt  356 root root 122880 Dec 31 05:20 tmp`. Also, I believe all the above commands I mentioned uses the same /tmp directory, so why it would work for one and not for others is I am unable to understand.

Comment: May I ask to show us the permission for that file on each host?

What makes me wonder is the following line:

Even normal copy fails: cp /usr/U91/host-a/trace/server_console_host-a.trc /tmp/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/tmp/server_console_host-a.trc’: Permission denied

Comment: Both are same:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 user sys 203529 Dec 29 11:54 server_console_host-a.trc` for host a and 
`-rw-r--r-- 1 user sys 3791296 Dec 31 05:31 server_console_host-b.trc` for host b.

Comment: strange...does it work as another user or to a different target (like users home DIR)?

Comment: I identified the issue. There was already a file with same name in /tmp that belonged to a different owner so the scp failed since it did not have the permission to overwrite the existing file due to different user. scp worked correctly after removing the file from /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

for `/tmp` directory if you will check the access by using `ls -l` (running at parent of tmp),

you will be getting `rwxrwxrwt`

*or*

in simple way you don't have `execute` permission so that you can perform delete/override operation inside directory using scp command.

In this case let `/tmp` folder already contains the file with same name which you want to copy then for this override operation will be done and you do not have that permission.

**Solution 1:** Rename your local file which is to be copied at server and use updated file name in your command.

*or*

**Solution 2:** Rename/remove the file *(which has same file name as local)* from `/tmp`.

*or*

**Solution 3:** Give `execute` access to the account which you are using.